# Splitting a datetime and replace the year part

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I need to split a date like '01/12/15' and replace the year part from 15 to 2015 (ie; 01-12-2015). I get the year by the sql query:

```
select YEAR('10/12/15')
```

It returns the year 2015. but I have to replace 15 to 2015. how do i achieve this. 
Anyone here please help me. thanks  in advance..

Edited:

I've tried following query too..

```
declare @date  varchar='10/12/2015' 
declare @datenew date

SELECT @datenew=CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CAST(@date AS DATETIME), 103)    

print @datenew
```

but it throws some error like this :
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How do I change the varchar to date and replace its year part to 4 digit.. please help me..

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT,@date varchar(150),@payperiod numeric(18,0),@emp_Id  varchar(50)
SET @intFlag = 1  
declare @count as int set @count=(select count(*) from @myTable)  
WHILE   (@intFlag <=@count)  
BEGIN    
select @emp_Id=Employee_Id from @myTable where rownum=@intFlag     
select @date=attendance_date from @myTable where rownum=@intFlag    
declare @datenew datetime 
SELECT @datenew=convert(datetime,CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CAST(@date AS DATETIME), 103) ,103)
```

It throws the error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: Is that October 12, or December 10?

Comment: My date is Dec10 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said your column is in `varchar` type, try the following

**Query**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
   dt VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
('01/12/15'),
('02/12/15'),
('03/12/15'),
('04/12/15'),
('05/12/15');

UPDATE #temp
SET dt = REPLACE(LEFT(dt, LEN(dt) - 2) 
       + CAST(YEAR(CAST(dt AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR(4)), '/', '-');

SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

**EDIT**

While declaring the variable `@date` you have not specified the length.

Check the below sql query.

```
declare @date  varchar(10)='10/12/2015' 
declare @datenew date
SELECT @datenew=CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CAST(@date AS DATETIME), 103)   
print @datenew
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way by casting Date object to VARCHAR

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAST(YEAR('10/12/15') AS VARCHAR), 2)
```

Comment: Yeah. it returns 12-10-2015.. but the format here MM-DD-YY, I need DD-MM-YY fromat. so what do i do?

Answer (score 1):

What datatype is the value `'01/12/15'`?

Maybe this will help you:

```
SELECT YEAR(CAST('10/12/15' AS DATE))
```

Comment: I need to change the date fromat.. 01/12/15 is in varchar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the format and get the varchar try to use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST('10/12/15' AS DATETIME), 105)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your query is that you haven't specified length for `varchar` datatype:

```
declare @date  varchar(12)='10/12/2015' 
declare @datenew date

SELECT @datenew=CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CAST(@date AS DATETIME), 103)    

print @datenew
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
Declare @date  nvarchar(20)='10/12/15' 
Declare @datenew nvarchar(40)
SELECT @datenew=CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CAST(@date AS DATETIME), 103)    
Print @datenew
```